# How do I know whether a process has active timer associated with it?

Tags: timer, process, linux-kernel

In Linux kernel 2.6.18, how can I know whether a process has active timers associated with it? Since the process is represented by the task_struct structure, I am trying to find whether task_struct has fields related to the active timers. In kernel 2.4.18, I do see such field called struct timer_list real_timer, which I believe contains the active timers owned by the process. However, in kernel 2.6.18, real_timer is removed from task_struct.

So does anyone know how to access the active timers owned by a process given the task_struct process descriptor in kernel 2.6?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "timer"? There are many things that could be called that.

Comment: In kernel 2.4.18, task_struct has a field struct timer_list real_timer. It is a periodic timer. But in kernel 2.6, this timer has been removed. I am just wondering where it is or if there is any equivalent timer in kernel 2.6.

Comment: `struct timer_list` still exists, but there are other kinds of timers. Why do you need to know about timers? And what exactly do you mean with "associated with"?

Comment: I am porting some legacy driver code to a new kernel. Yes, struct timer_list still exists, but there is no such filed in struct task_struct. By "associated with", I mean the process may have created some timers. Then we should have a way of knowing whether that process created timers or what timers it created. Hope this makes my purpose clearer.

Comment: Why do you need to know if some process created timers?